# Necessary of reduction to finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, finitely-generated

Sorry for my bad English.

In Hartshorne, III.Lemma 12.3, we prove $h^i(L^{\cdot}\otimes M)\cong h^i(C^{\cdot}\otimes M)$ as follows.

[image]

But, Im trouble that why he had to reduct to “$M$ is finitely generated”.

In other words, where we use “$M$ is finitely generated”.

Help me,thanks.

Comment: The next sentence after the highlight says where it's used. Is your question rather "why do we need to assume $E$ finitely generated?"

Comment: You are right. But I don’t have idea.